# Multiple Duplicated Layers in Photoshop like Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a way to duplicate layers in Photoshop, similar to Illustrator?

In Photoshop & Illustrator you can use the select tool and press the alt key to move and duplicate a layer. But in Illustrator after I duplicate the layer I can press **Ctrl D** to keep duplicating the layers in a equal distance apart.

Indesign can also do this by pressing Shift, Ctrl, Alt & D at the same time.

As far as I know Photoshop can not do this.

Does anyone know if this can be done in Photoshop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup.... `Edit > Transform... > Again`

[image]

**However**, this won't work when duplicating layers. You can simply use <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to duplicate layers.

Note that Illustrator does not duplicate layers either. It duplicates object transformations on the *same* layer. The difference is that Illustrator can have an *object* stack in addition to the Layer stack. There is no object stack in Photoshop.

Comment: Great answer and great explanation I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

it is enough to use “actions”.

1. you create a new action.
2. moves the object holding the Option/Alt.
3. stops the action.
4. Click on the Play >.
5. Done.